# Binary Indicator Conditional on Value of Day of TimeStamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, conditional-statements

In SQL Server, how do I create a new column that indicates `value > 0.5` only once for a given day?

For example, a value above 0.51 can occur multiple times a day, however the first time in a 24-hour period a value above 0.51 occurs, I want to indicate that. After a value above 0.51 occurs the second time the indicator must be 0.

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
| J1|2016-10-01 11:45:30| 0.49|
| J1|2016-10-01 12:30:30| 0.51|
| J1|2016-10-01 13:20:00| 0.49|
| J1|2016-10-02 11:45:30| 0.44|
| J1|2016-10-03 11:30:30| 0.52|
| J1|2016-10-03 12:20:00| 0.49|
| J9|2016-10-06 08:35:00| 0.51|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00| 0.44|
| J9|2016-10-07 08:35:00| 0.44|
| J9|2016-10-07 09:20:00| 0.53|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|               date|value| indicator|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
| J1|2016-10-01 11:45:30| 0.49|         0|
| J1|2016-10-01 12:30:30| 0.51|         1|
| J1|2016-10-01 13:20:00| 0.52|         0|
| J1|2016-10-01 14:45:30| 0.44|         0|
| J1|2016-10-02 11:30:30| 0.99|         1|
| J1|2016-10-02 12:20:00| 0.40|         0|
| J1|2016-10-02 08:35:00| 0.98|         0|
| J1|2016-10-02 09:20:00| 0.97|         0|
| J9|2016-10-07 08:35:00| 0.51|         1|
| J9|2016-10-07 09:20:00| 0.51|         0|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number`

```
select t.*, case when value > 0.5 then
  case when row_number() over (partition by case when value > 0.5 then 1 else 0 end, cast([date] as date) order by [date]) != 1 then 
    0 
  else 
    1 
  end 
 else 0 end rn
 from t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case when value > 0.5
        and sum(case when value > 0.5 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id, convert(date, date) order by date) = 1
    then 1 else 0 end as indicator
from mytable t
```

Comment: thanks for showing this. How would you do a cumulative sum instead of a regular sum?

Comment: @Starbucks: that's a cumulative sum already (the `order by` clause of the window function does that). This query does what you ask for.

Comment: @GMB... From what I can tell this is missing the "the first time in a 24-hour period" criteria by partitioning solely on the ID  column